# Python Error - Calculating Feature Geometry

Tags: python-2.7, arcgis

I have a line of code in a GIS script tool that keeps giving me an error of "TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable". It is to calculate the geometry of line features - the line begin and end point XY coordinates.

I do not know why I keep getting this error. Help is appreciated.

```
#Calcluate X & Y Values Of Network Begin/End Points
arcpy.CalculateGeometryAttributes_management(outfc, [["X_BEG", "LINE_START_X", "FEET_US"], ["Y_BEG", "LINE_START_Y", "FEET_US"]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your length unit "FEET_US" needs to be moved outside of the geometry properties lists and added as a separate input after the geometry properties

```
#Calcluate X & Y Values Of Network Begin/End Points
arcpy.CalculateGeometryAttributes_management(outfc, [["X_BEG", "LINE_START_X"], ["Y_BEG", "LINE_START_Y"]], "FEET_US")
```

See: [ESRI documentation for Calculate Geometry Attributes Code Sample](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-geometry-attributes.htm#C_GUID-D5A11E57-1B09-4DD5-A668-625FD495CA95)

Comment: Thank you! I finally came to a resolution; apparently in ArcMap 10.6, the "Calculate Geometry" tool was not included in the Toolbox. Trying what you mentioned just brings up another error. I was able to find a work around using the "Calculate Field" tool and specifying a geometry type.